# Noise in a particular region of the Rendered image

Tags: rendering, texturing

I made a cup with some texture but when i render it i have noise in a particular region. No matter what render settings i keep the problem still persists. I am attaching the blender file and the rendered image here. Please let me know to solve this issue.

[image: Noise image]

Blender file and the texture image link:-

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HICa-N4n3OdHY62WamhdYOW9JVvQ76rl?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake by connecting the noise texture Fac to the shader in mix shader instead of connecting it to the fac.

Thank you.